# How to solve this coupled differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dx}{dt} = (\iota a - c\cos(\omega t))x + \iota y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = (\iota a - c\cos(\omega t + \phi))y + \iota x$

I can solve it for $\phi = 0$ by taking addition and subtraction of the equations but how to go about it for non-zero $\phi$? $a$, $c$, and $\omega$ are constants.

Comment: $\phi$ is also constant. Forgot to add! Even if someone could direct me towards a book/research paper/etc. where such differential equations have been discussed, that would be super helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Maple gives a closed form in terms of the Heun doubly confluent function, implemented by $\texttt{HeunD()}$, and its derivative; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun_function